# Pandas remove non-alphanumeric characters from string column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

with pandas and jupyter notebook I would like to delete everything that is not character, that is: hyphens, special characters etc etc

es:

```
firstname,birthday_date
joe-down§,02-12-1990
lucash brown_ :),06-09-1980
^antony,11-02-1987
mary|,14-12-2002
```

change with:

```
firstname,birthday_date
joe down,02-12-1990
lucash brown,06-09-1980
antony,11-02-1987
mary,14-12-2002
```

I'm trying with:

```
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace(r'!', '')
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace(r'^', '')
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace(r'|', '')
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace(r'§', '')
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace(r':', '')
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace(r')', '')

......
......
df
```

it seems to work, but on more populated columns I always miss some characters.
Is there a way to completely eliminate all NON-text characters and keep only a single word or words in the same column? in the example I used firstname to make the idea better! but it would also serve for columns with whole words!

Thanks!

**P.S also encoded text for emoticons**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex for this.

```
df['firstname'] = df['firstname'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
df.firstname.tolist()
>>> ['joe down', 'lucash brown', 'antony', 'mary']
```

Comment: It seems to work, wouldn't it be better not to let space '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', with:  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '',    or it's the same thing ?

Comment: As unspoken ... the words remain united ... I thought it was the replacement space :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. It works on the names you have used in post

```
first_names = ['joe-down§','lucash brown_','^antony','mary|']
clean_names = []
keep = {'-',' '}
for name in first_names:
    clean_names.append(''.join(c if c not in keep else ' ' for c in name if c.isalnum() or c in keep))
print(clean_names)
```

output

```
['joe down', 'lucash brown', 'antony', 'mary']
```